# Conditional format on indirect value (after change)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to get a conditional format (for instance red background) when the value from the `indirect` (used in column B in my example here below) is not correct.
In normal use, when you first select the category in column A, and then B, everything is correct, but if I change the value in column A, the value in column B should be red if it's not part of the "indirect" range.
I tried `AND(indirect(A4))` in B4 but it's not returning a true or false value.
See screenshots if it's not clear:

In normal use:

[image: in normal use]

After changing value A4

[image: after changing value in A4, B2 should be red]

Comment: `AND(indirect(A4))`, what does this mean? `AND()` has two input parameters, hasn't it?

Comment: @Dominique You have to give at least one parameter for the AND formula. For instance I often check of a cell is empty or not with `AND(B4<>"")`.
I was thinking something similar would be possible with the INDIRECT formula but it isn't (because it's not returning a true or false value).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the `INDEX` formula.
In a hidden column I store the subcategories `INDEX(INDIRECT(A4);1)` and `INDEX(INDIRECT(A4);2)`, then I check in cell B4 if it's one of these values. It's not that complex because I only have 1 or 2 subcategories. If you would have 10 for instance it would become too complex I guess.